# When filling forms, should I use the masculine or feminine form of nationality adjective?

Tags: adjectifs, accord

When filling a form (e.g. for visa application) that asks for my *nationalité*, how do I decide whether I should use the masculine or feminine form?  I'm stuck between the two alternatives:

- The word should agree with my own gender;
- The word should answer the question *« De quelle nationalité êtes-vous ? »* Therefore, it should agree with the word *nationalité* itself, i.e. feminine.

In practice, which one is more acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second hypothesis is the right one : the correct adjective is always feminine, because "nationalité" is feminine. It has nothing to do with you own gender.

See this discussion, which goes in the same direction :

[discussion about "nationalité" gender](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=314189&langid=6)

Comment: L'affirmation générale selon laquelle l'adjectif serait « toujours » au féminin parce que le nom est féminin serait cependant inexacte dans certains cas similaires comme l'_origine ethnique_  avec par exemple « [Bengali](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bengali) ».